# Deepin Desktop Environment on WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I know its early to ask but has anybody out there had any luck running latest Deepin Desktop Environment (DDE) on WSL2 like you can run xfce4 through an X-server like Xming or VcXsrv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Starting from Ubuntu 20.04:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install ubuntudde-dde

sudo service dbus start
```

**To display using rdp:**

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp

sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
```

**To display using X11:**

```
export DISPLAY=[DISPLAY IP]:[DISPLAY NUMBER].0

deepin-session
```

Comment: `bash: export: \`IP]:[DISPLAY': not a valid identifier`